# Can I predict if my sequence is exchangeable?

Tags: exchangeability

Supppose I have a sequence as so (which we can really think of as a sequence of smaller sequences):

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1], [2 2 2 2 2 2], [3 3 3 3 3 3], [4 4 4 4 4 4]]
```

Is it exchangeable? Is it not? Why? It is a fairly loose question I know, but I am trying to understand how to answer this question.

Comment: Without some reference to a probability distribution this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok that's a good start; what does one _need_ to know how to answer this? I'm new to exchangeability.

Comment: You need to have information, if only partial, about the joint probability of the entire sequence.  *Exchangeability* is a property of that joint distribution (or of the vector random variable used to model the data), after all.  It's not a property of any particular sequence. If some textbook or professor is asking to you determine, merely by inspection, whether this *sequence* of vectors is "exchangeable," then they are using a non-standard definition of the term, so any answer must begin with that definition.

Comment: Is the grouping in your data an aspect of the data, or have you just grouped it this way to highlight the repeated values.  In other words, is your data a vector of 24 scalar values, or is it a vector of 4 vector values, each consisting of 6 elements?

Comment: Hi! The data is an index type array where each entry has a N repetitions (6 above). The grouping above is artificial and it is really 24 scalar values but which have this ordinal and repetitive structure.

Comment: @whuber but if all that I know is that these are counting values (repeated) then can I actually say anything about exchangeability? I.e. These number are used to index things, where the first batch of 1s eg index six other objects